# Maven: plugin to fail a build if a string is found

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin

During development, I have an habit of wrapping code that should not be in production inside "TODEL" tag. For example:

```
//TODEL - START

//used to test the crashing behavior
String s = null;
int i = s.length;

//TODEL - END
```

Is there a maven plugin that can fail a build in jenkins if I accidentally checkin a file that contains "TODEL"?

Comment: Are your sure you don't want to instead write a trigger for your versioning system, to prevent you from checking in the code in the first place?

Comment: If you're using eclipse you can set up a rule in Checkstyle  plugin that marks that.

Answer (score 5):

One thing you can do is to use `maven checkstyle plugin` . You can set up a rule and the make the build fail if it is not compliant to those rules.

```
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
   <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
   <configuration>
       <configLocation>my-checkstyle.xml</configLocation>
   </configuration>
</plugin>
```

The configuration property `maven.checkstyle.fail.on.violation`.

Then `mvn checkstyle:check`. Or configure it to execute in a phase of your choice (compile or process-resources) by adding to the plugin configuration:

```
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
   <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
   <executions>
       <execution>
           <id>TODEL</id>
           <configuration>
               <configLocation>my-checkstyle.xml</configLocation>
           </configuration>
           <goals>
               <goal>check</goal>
           </goals>
           <phase>validate</phase>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

More info: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-checkstyle-plugin

Comment: Perhaps I'd use PMD instead of Checkstyle, but apart from that: +1